# Spring Security: Access URL from Angular outside of context

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, angular5, jhipster

I have generated a JHipster (4.13.1) application. On the backend I have a Spring boot application with Spring security configured like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .key(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getRememberMe().getKey())
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
        .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").fullyAuthenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);

}
```

On the frontend I have a Angular (5) client that makes a REST call to the Spring boot application. I login from Angular as follows:

```
login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    const data = 'j_username=' + encodeURIComponent(credentials.username) +
        '&j_password=' + encodeURIComponent(credentials.password) +
        '&remember-me=' + credentials.rememberMe + '&submit=Login';
    const headers = new Headers ({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });

    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/authentication', data, { headers });
}
```

After login I can make any call, for example "this.http.get(url)".

Now I have two buttons. ButtonOne makes a call within the context (for example http://localhost:8080) and ButtonTwo make remote REST call (for example to http://serverx:8080). I have enabled cors in the application.yml

```
cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: "*"
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers: "Link,X-Total-Count"
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

The first works (as I am logged in) and the second triggers authentication (http 401). I like to reuse the credentials to access the remote API. What is the proper way to authenticate/access urls outside the context from Angular?

I found the following resources on calling remote Rest API:

[separating-front-end-and-api](https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/)

[swagger-cli](https://github.com/cbornet/generator-jhipster-swagger-cli)

BTW: When using the JHipster microservice Gateway/Application configuration this use case works, because I can stay in my own context and call rest API through the registry. But I want to avoid the registry as the application must work standalone.

Comment: What do you mean by *and another one outside (for example http://10.0.2.15:8080).*? Is that another application or the same but with IP address instead of loopback?

Comment: Both. In this example it is the same application with a different IP address, but it can also be another instance of the same application running on another server (share same database/users).